# How can in upload custom product video

Tags: magento2.3, product-video

I saw having option to add video from Vimeo and Youtube.

Can i upload video directly from admin product page?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You need to generate the Youtube and Vimeo API keys in order to embed videos. You can configure the API key in **Stores->Configuration->Catalog->Product Video**. Once saved you can go to your admin product page. You can find **Add Videos** in **Images and Videos** section. You can add the video URL, title, description and preview image there. Save it and check the frontend to see the video.

Update:

You can directly add a video by creating a custom module or you can add the video in **Content Section** of your product page in Admin. You can add the video directly in your media folder and then embed it using video tag.

```
<video controls="controls" width="800" height="400">
  <source src="{{media url='/catalog/file_name.mp4'}}" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

Comment: Yeah, i refer that. I like to know upload video directly to product page with out using in Youtube and Vimeo URL

Comment: Please find the updated answer

Comment: HI @RajMohanR, 
Your solution is for displaying video in product detail page in either description or in tabbing section but if i want to display video inside Product Image gallery (fotorama gallery), do you have any idea how to do with this for configurable product..